How to convert a matplotlib plot data into JSON file to run in my react component?
So, my friend has a ML model which does a prediction based on a company's stock. The output is displayed using matplotlib plot graph and it does the job. Now, I have a react based website in which I want to integrate the plot graph. So, I tried the img display method but that will cause issues in dynamic running.
So, I tried converting the python plot graph into data using mpdl3 module and then converted it to JSON object using the following code:
import json
import mpld3
fig=plt.gcf()
mpld3_data = mpld3.fig_to_dict(fig)
print(mpld3_data);
mpld3_data_str = json.dumps(mpld3_data)
with open('mpld3_data.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(mpld3_data, f)

It does give me a JSON file and I can import it to my react file. Upon importing it into a JS file, I parsed it there using the following code:
import mpld3_data from "...file location..."
var graph_data=JSON.parse(mpld3_data);
export default graph_data

But while running the file, it throws me a "Module not found" error.
PS: Since, it is a python code, the code and the JSON file it produces is outside my src file. So, I have to import it using relative path.
I don't know what should I do here and what approach would be better. Thank you for your help and I would really appreciate it.
